# SQL speed issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using PostgreSQL and want to use a query like this:

```
SELECT  device, value, id 
FROM  myTable s 
WHERE (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM myTable f WHERE f.id = s.id AND f.value >= s.value ) <= 2
```

This works but the problem is it takes minutes to execute over large data. Is there a faster way that can happen in seconds? What I am trying to do is take only two items from a row where both values are sorted in asc order.

```
id | device | value

1     123       40
1     456       30
1     789       45
2     12        10
2     11        9
```

The above is my table (I know ids are not unique, not my design, but it has a purpose) but within the id lets say id = 1, I want to select id, device and value of the smallest 2, so my result would be 1, 123, 30 and 1, 456, 40 and so on for other ids.

Also, if anyone knows, if you insert sorted data into a database is it a guarantee to read back out in the same order?

Comment: Regarding your first question: run `EXPLAIN` (although it looks like you are trying to do a join). Regarding your second question: no always specify the `ORDER BY`

Comment: "*if you insert sorted data into a database is it a guarantee to read back out in the same order*" that's a clear: **NO**. Unless you are using an `order by` in your query the database is free to chose any order in which it wants to return the rows

Comment: I'd avoid a correlated subquery, especially if an appropriate index is not available (with `id` and `value` as the leading columns, in that order.) If I was looking for the rows with the "highest two values" for each row, I'd probably use a window function, like **`dense_rank`**. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-window.html (Could you seriously *not* find any similar questions?) If you want a result returned in a particular sequence, add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks everyone so far, I edited it and hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try below query:

```
SELECT s.device,s.id,s.value
FROM myTable s
INNER JOIN myTable f ON s.id = f. id AND f.value >= s.value
GROUP BY s.device,s.id,s.value
HAVING COUNT(s.id) <= 2
```

Comment: This works quite well thank you. I don't think I quite understand why? And is it possible to add one more sort on the id after the value sort? Also, thanks for not being rude, I never claimed to be great at SQL nor a great writer. Like the snark above....

Comment: Please accept this answer if you are ok with it. As far as sorting is concern you can add any number of columns in you order by clause after having clause but make sure that column must also be there in group by column list.

Comment: I am thanks, as soon as it lets me I will accept as the official answer. My guess is that it runs faster because of the inner join?